# question how do you display content that is stored in the firebase in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile

```
useEffect(() => {
  todoRef.orderBy('createAt', 'desc').onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
    const todos = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const { heading } = doc.data();
      todos.push({ id: doc.id, heading });
    });
    setTodos(todos);
  });
}, []);

//dealate a todo from firebase database

const dealateTodo = (todos) => {
  todoRef
    .doc(todos, id)
    .delete()
    .then(() => {
      // Show a successful alert after deleting
      alert('Deleted Successfully');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      alert(error);
    });
};

// add a todo
const addTodo = (todo) => {
  // checking is there a todo in here
  if (addData && addData.length > 0) {
    // get the timestamp
    const timestamp = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
    const data = {
      heading: addData,
      createdAt: timestamp,
    };
    todoRef
      .add(data)
      .then(() => {
        setAddData('');
        Keyboard.dismiss();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error);
      });
  }
};

return (
  <View style={styles.flex_1}>
    <ScrollView
      data={todos}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View>
          <Pressable
            style={styles.container}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Detail', { item })}
          >
            <FontAwesome
              name='trash'
              color='red'
              onPress={() => dealateTodo(item)}
              style={styles.todoIcon}
            />
            <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.itemHeading}>
                [item.Heading[0].toUpperCase() + item.heading.slice(1)]
              </Text>
            </View>
          </Pressable>
        </View>
      )}
    />
    <View style={styles.formContainer}>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.txt_input}
        placeholder='Enter Task Title'
        placeholderTextColor='#aaaaaa'
        onChangeText={(heading) => setAddData(heading)}
        value={addData}
        underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
        autoCapitalize='none'
      />
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={addTodo}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>+</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  </View>
);
```

I wrote This code to display the Data stored in the firebase but it doesn't display can anyone help?
please! (comment if you need the full file)

Comment: could you include the render part of the code in the post

Comment: done, could you help me?

Comment: @vastal soni can you help me?

Comment: can try to log `item` so you know you are receiving data

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `ScrollView` and try to use it like a `FlatList`. The `ScrollView` does not define a `renderItem` or `data` prop. Use a `FlatList` or use the `map` function to `map` over `todos`.

Furthermore, you need to add `{}` around code that you are calling for objects within a component not `[]`.

Here is a version using `FlatList`.

```js
<FlatList
      data={todos}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View>
          <Pressable
            style={styles.container}
          >
          
            <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.itemHeading}>
                {item.Heading[0].toUpperCase() + item.heading.slice(1)}
              </Text>
            </View>
          </Pressable>
        </View>
      )}
    />
```

Here is a version using `ScrollView` and `map`.

```js
<ScrollView>
     {
       todos.map(item => <View>
          <Pressable
            style={styles.container}
          >
          
            <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.itemHeading}>
                {item.Heading[0].toUpperCase() + item.heading.slice(1)}
              </Text>
            </View>
          </Pressable>
        </View>)
     }
    </ScrollView>
```